# Google Play Movies & TV has stopped - but not even installed

Tags: force-close, google-play-movies

Around 2-3 times a week I'm getting this popup error - but the app isn't even installed!
Any idea what's going on? Is it hiding in another Google app and that's why I don't find it?
I couldn't find any rule for when it happens - while scrolling Facebook, browser, while idle... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

What can I do about it?

**Popup error:**

[image]

**The app isn't installed:** (It's the full list, including system apps)

[image]

*Device details: LG G5; Android 7.0; stock ROM; no root.*

Comment: This is just a theory; I'll make it an answer if you confirm this case. Under Apps>Default>Set as Default, you have the option enabled 'Open links in apps' even if they are not installed, and the dialog happens when you try to view a movie? It could be trying to satisfy this request using the non-present app.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any link that seems related, and the Movies app wasn't in the app links list. When you say "try to view a movie" - what do you mean? With what app? Also, the Movies & TV isn't available in my country yet if that changes anything (in play store - "This app is incompatible with your device.").

Comment: Movies is actually under `store` right? So maybe it tries to open something with my store app, that doesn't support it? If so, where this requests can come from?

Comment: I was thinking under the concept of 'Instant Apps' which allow non-installed apps to work as a proxy. Read [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211/). Those requests could be yours, or, it seems, even pushed to you through others (in their case, a message).

Comment: Oh that, I only have Vimeo on there, and the option is enabled in general.